# Separate HTML, CSS, and JavaScript don't work in templated html in appScript

Tags: google-apps-script

Following https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices, if I add a function to open the dialog, the separated resources do not work in the .html and I obtain:

[image]

My code is the exact same one as in the example, adding `openDialog` and `onOpen` function to open the dialog.

Code.gs:

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

// Use this code for Google Docs, Slides, Forms, or Sheets.
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Dialog')
      .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}
```

Page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Please enjoy this helpful script.</p>
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet.html:

```
<style>
p {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

Javascript.html:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Page is loaded');
});
</script>
```

Screenshot to check filenames are correct:
[image]

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I found the duplicated questions. So, I deleted my answer and I flagged it as a duplicate question. If I misunderstood your question, please tell me.